# Using "and" vs "or" in a list

Tags: conjunctions, lists

This has really been bothering me.  Which of these is the most correct?

> I am against twabulation except in the cases of delivery, attack,
> and colorization of a twibble.
>
> I am against twabulation except in the cases of delivery, attack,
> or colorization of a twibble.

(swapping "in" and "for")

> I am against twabulation except for the cases of delivery, attack,
> and colorization of a twibble.
>
> I am against twabulation except for the cases of delivery, attack,
> or colorization of a twibble.

Googling these kind of sentence structures reveals a mostly even split among the number of search results.

Comment: They are all correct in their own way. Changing conjunctions and prepositions actually changes the meaning, not the correctness. Which meaning are you intending?

Comment: Here is the long form: "I am against twabulation in the case of delivery.  I am against twabulation in the case of attack.  I am against twabulation in the case of colorization of a twibble.  For all other cases, I am in favor of twabulation."

Answer (score 2):

There is a slight difference in your first two sentences. First, the difference between "and" and "or":

> 1) I am against twablulation except in the cases of delivery, attack,
>   and colorization of a twibble.
>
> 2) I am against twablulation except in the cases of delivery, attack,
>   or colorization of a twibble.

Sentence 1) refers to cases in which a twibble is affected by **all three** (delivery, attack, and colorization)
Sentence 2) refers to cases in which a twibble is affected by **one or more** (delivery and/or attack and/or colorization)

> 3) I am against twablulation except for the cases of delivery, attack,
>   and colorization of a twibble.
>
> 4) I am against twablulation except for the cases of delivery, attack,
>   or colorization of a twibble.

As for sentences 3) and 4), they sound odd because of your use of "for" instead of "in". "Except for..." can be a correct construction, but the "for" is not necessary. In this case I would write "except in cases of..." - the fewer prepositions, the better.

Comment: If you use a disjunctive "or" then what if a twibble is attacked _and_ colorized? Some interpretations of disjunctive say that the forms are mutually exclusive so it is unclear if you are against twablulation. More annoying: "and" is usually conjunctive (all three must happen), but sometimes "and" is disjunctive. I did a little Googling, but got annoyed with bad memories of Statutory Interpretation class, and I decided to just write a comment. Note that some jurisdictions define "or" and "and" because the grammar is not always obvious. See http://law.justia.com/codes/louisiana/2011/ccrp/ccrp6